Why I cannot move from this activity to any other?
I'm developing a mobile Java app in Android Studio. I've created several activities, a menu to navigate between them and a toolbar to be at the top of each page. However, I'm facing a problem when navigating (trying to navigare, to be more correct) from Lorries activity as it turns out I'm totally unable to navigate from it, though no problems arise when moving from any other activity.
I'm fresh new to mobile development and will be extremely grateful for your help and attention!
Here's the code of LorriesActivity.java (I bet the issue is somewhere here)
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class LorriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ImageView menu;
    LinearLayout timetable, messages, orders, lorries, drivers, clients, partners, company;
    LinearLayout logout;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_lorry_button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lorries);
        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        menu=findViewById(R.id.menu);
        timetable=findViewById(R.id.timetable);
        messages=findViewById(R.id.messages);
        orders=findViewById(R.id.orders);
        lorries=findViewById(R.id.lorries);
        drivers=findViewById(R.id.drivers);
        clients=findViewById(R.id.clients);
        partners=findViewById(R.id.partners);
        company=findViewById(R.id.company);
        logout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        add_lorry_button = findViewById(R.id.add_lorry_button);
        add_lorry_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        });
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDrawer(drawerLayout);
            }
        });
        timetable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            }
        });
        messages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, MessagesActivity.class);
            }
        });
        orders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, OrdersActivity.class);
            }
        });
        lorries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { recreate(); }
        });
        drivers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, DriversActivity.class);
            }
        });
        clients.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, ClientsActivity.class);
            }
        });
        partners.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, PartnersActivity.class);
            }
        });
        company.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redirectActivity(LorriesActivity.this, CompanyActivity.class);
            }
        });
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(LorriesActivity.this,"Ви вийшли з системи",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void openDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout){
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    public static void closeDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout){
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
    public static void redirectActivity(Activity activity, Class secondActivity){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity,secondActivity);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        activity.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }
}

And this is the code of activity_lorries.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".LorriesActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Вантажівки"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_lorry_button"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


I fixed it! All I needed to do is move the relative layout with the nav drawer to the very end of a layout file.
